# Mac OS X seems to be unable to find directory that certainly exists

Tags: macos, bash, shell, mount

For some reason Mac OS X cannot find a directory I just made. Any idea why?

```
sh-3.2# mkdir /Users/Administrator/Documents/drive/
sh-3.2# mount -w -t "hfs+" /dev/disk1s2 /Users/Administrator/Documents/drive/
mount: exec /System/Library/Filesystems/hfs+.fs/Contents/Resources/mount_hfs+ for /Users/Administrator/Documents/drive: No such file or directory
```

UPDATE:

I tried to run

```
bbcs:/ Administrator$ sudo mount_hfs /dev/disk1s2 /Users/Administrator/Documents/drive/
Password:
mount_hfs: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your [`mount`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount.8.html) filesystem type of `hfs+` which I don’t even see in my local Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) setup when I run `ls -l1 /System/Library/Filesystems/`:

```
AppleShare
NetFSPlugins
acfs.fs
afpfs.fs
cd9660.fs
cddafs.fs
exfat.fs
ftp.fs
hfs.fs
msdos.fs
nfs.fs
ntfs.fs
smbfs.fs
udf.fs
webdav.fs
```

So my advice would be to just run the command like this; note the removal of the trailing (`+`) as well as the double-quotes (`"`):

```
mount -w -t hfs /dev/disk1s2 /Users/Administrator/Documents/drive/
```

Another idea is to run the command as [`sudo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) like this for your original command:

```
sudo mount -w -t "hfs+" /dev/disk1s2 /Users/Administrator/Documents/drive/
```

Or this for the modified example adjustment I made:

```
sudo mount -w -t hfs /dev/disk1s2 /Users/Administrator/Documents/drive/
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Jake, I ran the command as you suggested but I get "invalid Argument" Error, that being said I ran couple varieties of it as well and it seems that it was `hfs`(without +) that yields that error, `hfs+` without quotes yeilds my original error.

Comment: I should the noted this on beginning I have been running all commands with help of su. Tha being said I the mean while I tired to run `mount_hfs` which gave me "Invalid Arguments" again which makes me wonder if "hfs" could somehow be busted.